# How to remove layout anchor_property of fab in programmatically?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have added layout_anchor property on fab in layout xml. After clicking a button the fab should position on end of the screen. To achieve that I am thinking to add gravity property. But how do i remove layout_anchor property programmatically.

**layout.xml**

```
   <com.samsoft.sam.Fab
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/asd"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The above is my fab code and it positions perfectly, now I need to replace layout anchor property with android:gravity="top|end" programmatically. Please help me.

Comment: You do that in the Java code. Can we see it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you mean you want the `FloatingActionButton`'s `layout_gravity` to end up as `top|end`.

You can do this by getting the `FloatingActionButton`'s `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`, clearing the anchor's ID, setting the `gravity` field as needed, and then setting the `LayoutParams` back on the `FloatingActionButton`.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
lp.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | GravityCompat.END;
fab.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) floatingActionButton.getLayoutParams()).setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
```

This is the code you are looking for. Happy coding :)